# Xamarin Android MvvmCross bind facebook login button

Tags: c#, android, facebook, xamarin.android

Is it possible to bind default facebook login button to ViewModel?

my login button:

```
<com.facebook.login.widget.LoginButton
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/loginButton1"
/>
```

For now when I click on login button in my view I have to find my fb button and wait for click action. Is it possible to bind it to view model to do this business logic there??

**UPDATE 1**

One guy here showed me how to bind.. Yeah I know how to write the bind... To be more precise I need a viewmodel code example to deal with the facebook callbacks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes,

```
app:MvxBind="Click FacebookLoginCommand"
```

**UPDATE**

As for moving all code responsible for login with Facebook to Portable project it is not quite possible since Facebook SDK is design for and related with specific platform - in this case with Android. So maybe You can leave logging part in Android project and in ViewModel create methods:

```
OnFacebookLogginSuccess(string accessToken);
OnFacebookLogginError(string message);
```

and call them in facebook callback

```
ViewModel.OnUserIsLoggedToFacebook(result.AccessToken.Token)

ViewModel.OnFacebookLoginError(exception.LocalizedMessage)
```

Then since GraphApi can be accessed via simple HTTP calls you can query it in portable project .

Comment: Could you please show me what interfaces my viewmodel should inherit to deal with facebook callbacks? And it would be realy nice if you could show me `FacebookLoginCommandHandler()` code

Comment: okey, but tell me what You want to achieve? Because there are some parts that need to stay in android if you want to login using facebook SDK. So please describe more specifically your plan so I can help You.

Comment: So the scenario I need is quite simple... User opens app for the first time. Then he sees facebook login button and clicks it. He enters his credentials. Then facebook login mechanism works and `onSuccess` returns me a `LoginResult` object. With this object I need to make `GraphRequest` to get user's email.  And if user does not have email on his facebook, I need to open new form to fill email. After all the information I got, I need to save user to database. 

So I tought that most of this should be in ViewModel, because this task is not UI task, but more like business logic

Comment: Maybe you have some latest xamarin android mvvmCross app example with correct fb login and user saving to db?